# Thread Window in Visual Studio Express 2012 Desktop Edition

Tags: visual-studio

I recently migrated my project files to a new system and i'm using now visual studio 2012 Express Edition for Desktop  (Earlier was using Visual Studio 2010 professional). I'm not able to get thread window in the debugger by navigating onto **debug->windows->Threads** . How to find the thread window in visual studio 2012 express edition .

Comment: Is one of those menu items greyed out? Not there? Or you invoke the command and (something else | nothing) happens?

Comment: Its not there i get only three options namely 
1)Breakpoints
2)Output
3)Immediate

Comment: Are you in a debug session?  The additional window menu options are contextual and only appear during an active debug session.

Comment: I'm in debug session and i'm not able to see it.

Comment: Got the same now thanks . The issue can be closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it by going to the Quick Launch bar on the upper right corner of the UI or pressing Ctrl+Q. Then search for "threads". You should see a search result for the threads window.